# Helm k8s Jenkins agent fails to start up after editing config

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins, kubernetes-helm

#### My problem:

After installing Jenkins via Helm as shown below, when I
modify any config in Jenkins UI (e.g., change the podTemplate name to default -> default2),
test job (echo hello) fails.

My Jenkins agent fails to start up.

##### **Cluster details:**

Image:         jenkins/jenkins:2.401.3-jdk11

Kubernetes plugin Version : 4029.v5712230ccb_f8

Configuration as Code Version : 1647.ve39ca_b_829b_42

```
helm pull jenkins/jenkins
...
cd jenkins/jenkins
helm upgrade -i jenkins -n ops-jenkins . --create-namespace
```

```
$ kubectl get po -n ops-jenkins -w
NAME        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS      AGE
jenkins-0   2/2     Running   1 (21m ago)   29m
default2-jn08q   0/1     Pending             0             0s
default2-jn08q   0/1     Pending             0             0s
default2-jn08q   0/1     ContainerCreating   0             0s
default2-jn08q   0/1     Error               0             1s
default2-jn08q   0/1     Error               0             3s
default2-jn08q   0/1     Terminating         0             3s
default2-jn08q   0/1     Terminating         0             3s
default2-bjx6s   0/1     Pending             0             0s
default2-bjx6s   0/1     Pending             0             0s
default2-bjx6s   0/1     ContainerCreating   0             0s
default2-bjx6s   0/1     Error               0             2s
default2-bjx6s   0/1     Error               0             3s
default2-bjx6s   0/1     Terminating         0             3s
default2-bjx6s   0/1     Terminating         0             3s
default2-rsjrc   0/1     Pending             0             0s
default2-rsjrc   0/1     Pending             0             0s
default2-rsjrc   0/1     ContainerCreating   0             0s
default2-rsjrc   0/1     Error               0             2s
default2-rsjrc   0/1     Error               0             3s
default2-rsjrc   0/1     Terminating         0             3s
default2-rsjrc   0/1     Terminating         0             3s
```

```
$ kubectl describe po -n ops-jenkins
...
Events:
  Type    Reason     Age   From               Message
  ----    ------     ----  ----               -------
  Normal  Scheduled  3s    default-scheduler  Successfully assigned ops-jenkins/default2-j79tl to ip-10-30-100-8.us-west-2.compute.internal
  Normal  Pulled     2s    kubelet            Container image "jenkins/inbound-agent:3107.v665000b_51092-15" already present on machine
  Normal  Created    2s    kubelet            Created container jnlp
  Normal  Started    2s    kubelet            Started container jnlp
```

***If I restart Jenkins the modified configuration disappears, and the agent works fine again.***

##### A note:

It is possible it is related to the plugin below.

```
Kubernetes plugin Version : 4029.v5712230ccb_f8
Configuration as Code Version : 1647.ve39ca_b_829b_42
```

#### Where should I look for the problem, has anyone seen this before?

Thank you